# Liferay password validation

Tags: java, liferay-6

I created my own login portlet, so in order for user to login, he needs to give email address and password. My problem is, how can i compare the password in Database? the password in database is hashed something life this : 'AAAAoAAB9AAIOq5P5Lf2Ip2RoV3MynhtkU6s++nPknsVblKR'. I am using Liferay version 6.2.

Comment: You should edit your [first question](/questions/32878273/liferay-compare-encrypted-password) instead of opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look on isSameAsCurrentPassword function in this manual.

[liferay Password API Document](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/PasswordTrackerLocalService.html)

And I think you need to hash the input password first before using this function.